# WP how do I give different style to the content displayed in category.php

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

How do I use the same 'content' displayed on Index.php and content.php but with a completely different style class assigned to it when it is displayed in category.php? How can I specify it?

category.php

```
<section class="main">
            <div class="mod"><h5><?php printf( __( 'Recent %s &#92; ', 'twentytwelve' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) ); ?></h5></div>
            <ul id="franchise_list" class="tout_list">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /* Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
             * this in a child theme then include a file called called content-___.php
             * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format(), '<a class="franchise">' . single_cat_title() );

        endwhile;

        twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
        ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
```

Comment: `<section class="main different">` and then styled based on the class ?

Comment: u got it wrong, look at get_template_part where 'content' displays the content from content.php including its style, what I'm trying to do is display the same news content but with a different CSS assigned to it.. I hope I have explained right

Comment: To assign different styles you'll need a different selector to target. You can set a class to a parent element, and target all child elements using that class to set styles. If only one page has the different class, you get different styles.

Comment: The result I'm trying to achieve is pretty much same as having a different content.php that is there exclusively for category.php.. I don't know if I'm clear on what I'm saying, but hopefully.

Comment: I have no idea, but to style differently, you need different selectors -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rfnwg07q/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are using [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) wrong. You cannot add class to it. Look at the docs. This is the correct syntax

```
get_template_part( $slug, $name );
```

If you need a custom content file for a category, you can simply copy `content.php`, rename it `content-category.php`, add your custom classes and change what you need to change, save it and then in `category.php` change this line

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format(), '<a class="franchise">' . single_cat_title() );
```

to this

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'category' );
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, can't thank you enough!!